# Binding to ratio of heights

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I'm trying to create a grid with two panes with a grid splitter between them that the user can reposition at runtime. I'd also like to bind a variable representing the ratio of the two panes. I've tried the following XAML:

```
<local:CustomConverter x:Key="splitPositionConverter2"/>

<StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBox Name="txtValue" />
             <Grid x:Name="splitViewGrid" Height="400">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--The top panel height is bound to the SplitPosition property. -->
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=txtValue, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource splitPositionConverter2}}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid  Grid.Row="0" Background="Red"/>
            <GridSplitter  Grid.Row="1"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                           ResizeDirection="Rows"
                           Height="15"/>
            <Grid  Grid.Row="2" Background="Blue"/>
        </Grid>
 </StackPanel>
```

And I have the following converter:

```
public class CustomConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Double db = 0.0;
        if (Double.TryParse((string)value, out db))
            return new GridLength(db, GridUnitType.Star);    // value starts off as 2
        else
            return new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is GridLength)
        {
            GridLength GLen = (GridLength)value;
            return GLen.Value.ToString();  // is a very large number
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So a value of 2 should have the red block to be twice the height of the blue block. The conversion from data to height seems to work but the ConvertBack gives me some weird values. A small nudge will give me a value in ConvertBack of 260* or so.

Am I interpreting this value incorrectly or is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: splitter is also changing Height of the last row, from what I see, when run your sample. so ratio is `260/125` or so